# How to make a horizontal table with ngx-datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, ngx-datatable

Just like the title says. I'm using [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) with Angular 4 and I'm trying to create a horizontal table (header being the 1. column, and all other columns being filled with data). The default vertical layout makes no sense for me as I have only two properties. I couldn't find anything in the documentation or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of what you have in mind? Do you mean something like this?

```
-----------------------------------------------------
single header
-----------------------------------------------------
property 1    |    something   |    something   | etc
property 2    |    something   |    something   | etc
-----------------------------------------------------
```

If so, it sounds like you can use `ngx-datatable` and just hide all headers.

Comment: I have same problem. And hiding headers not a good solution :) Still you have any demo for your solution?